# How to pass string array to Web API action with PUT

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I'm aware of the [special requirements](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) (single parameter, empty key name, use `FormBody`) when passing simple types to Web API actions. But I couldn't get it to work with jQuery `$.ajax` and http `PUT`. The action is hit but the value is always `null`.

The controller's action is:

```
public class ValuesController: ApiController
{
    public void Put([FormBody]string value)
    {
    }
}
```

And the javascript is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'put',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: 'Values/',
    data: {'': '1,newValue'},
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
  [HttpPut]
    public void Put(person value)
    {
    }

public class person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
}

    $("#clickme").click(function () {
        var person = new Object();
        person.name = "Homer";
        person.surname = "Simpson";
        var value = person;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/blah',
            type: 'PUT',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: person,
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('Error in Operation');
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: If I use `$.post`, the value gets through, but it hits `POST` action instead of `PUT`.

Comment: I think put listens for 2 values in the result, you might try [HttpPut] on the void and see if that helps.

Comment: Did you mean to put `HttpPut` attribute to `POST` action?

Comment: I mean [HttpPut] public void Put([FormBody]string value)
    { 
    }

Comment: Still getting null after adding [HttpPut] to Put action.